# Link Ancora, como deixa-lo abrir em uma determinada posição da página

Tags: html, css, ancora

Seguinte, estou utilizando uma página com ancora em "abas", porém quando clico no link dentro da ABA ele abre certinho mais puxa para o TOP da página o id correspondente, e assim prejudica o MENU que está fixo na parte de cima (pois corre a página)

Gostaria de saber se têm como ao clicar no âncora do link, ele direcionar para uma posição definida. Pois o que acontece é ele levar o div #id até o topo do navegador.

Esse exemplo das abas é a melhor forma de explicar...

http://www.sonddenge.com.br/index.html#servicos

A ideia é a mesma

É como se clica-se na Ancora e nem mexia a página.... tira essa função do ancora de levar o ID até o top do navegador

Comment: Vi que utilizam isso... mas não entendi...    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */

Answer (score 1):

eu normalmente faço isso pelo id

**link desejado**

```
<a  href="test.html#id" target="_blank">NOME</a>
```

**Pagina de direccionamento**

```
<div id="id">
```

*id-pode colocar o que quiser, se colocar no div contacto então no link tem que colocar a seguir ao # contacto.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui,

Segue o que precisa ser colocado no BODY

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".service-info").hide(); 
  $("ul.services-aba li:first").addClass("services-aba-active").show();
  $(".service-info:first").show('slow');
 
  $("ul.services-aba li").click(function() {
   $("ul.services-aba li").removeClass("services-aba-active");
   $(this).addClass("services-aba-active"); 
 
   $(".service-info").hide(); 
   var activeaba = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
   $(activeaba).fadeIn('slow'); 
   return false;
  });
 
 });
```